# Как отловить последнее вхождение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

При этом не используя $

Пример текста: `Seq Scan on biba_holder  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.009 rows=63 loops=1)`

Нынешний вид регулярки: `rows=([[:digit:]]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйся регуляркой: `rows=([[:digit:]]+)(?!.*rows=([[:digit:]]+))`.

Ссылка на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/C8WbQR/1) для тестов. Скрин результата:

**Описание**:

`(?! ...)` - начало с текущей позиции в выражении гарантирует, что данный шаблон не будет совпадать.

`.*` - 0 или больше любых символов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]